# NPM won't install angular2

Tags: npm, angular

I'm trying to get started with Angular 2, and for some reason npm will not download it. I've run the update npm command several times, so it's not an npm issue.

I keep getting the following error:

```
error notarget No compatible version found: angular2@'*'
36 error notarget Valid install targets:
36 error notarget ["2.0.0-alpha.8.dev","2.0.0-alpha.8.prod","2.0.0-alpha.11","2.0.0-alpha.12","2.0.0-alpha.13","2.0.0-alpha.14","2.0.0-alpha.15","2.0.0-alpha.16","2.0.0-alpha.17","2.0.0-alpha.18","2.0.0-alpha.19","2.0.0-alpha.20","2.0.0-alpha.21","2.0.0-alpha.22","2.0.0-alpha.23","2.0.0-alpha.24","2.0.0-alpha.25","2.0.0-alpha.26","2.0.0-alpha.27","2.0.0-alpha.28","2.0.0-alpha.29","2.0.0-alpha.30","2.0.0-alpha.31","2.0.0-alpha.32"]
36 error notarget
```

This is such a ridiculous road block to hit trying to learn a framework.

Does anyone know how to fix this or if there is a download source that actually works ? I just want to get started with Angular2 =(

Comment: Try `npm install angular2@2.0.0-alpha.32`.

Comment: That worked ! If you put this as an answer ill mark it as correct =D

Comment: It doesn't answer your question but have you considered using JSPM? When you install it will automatically map the new module and all its dependencies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As requested, use the following line:

```
npm install angular2@2.0.0-alpha.32
```

Note that the error message gave a clue.
As shown below, the error message was trying to tell you what is valid after `angular2@`. `2.0.0-alpha.32` is currently the latest version.

```
Valid install targets:
["2.0.0-alpha.8.dev","2.0.0-alpha.8.prod","2.0.0-alpha.11","2.0.0-alpha.12","2.0.0-alpha.13","2.0.0-alpha.14","2.0.0-alpha.15","2.0.0-alpha.16","2.0.0-alpha.17","2.0.0-alpha.18","2.0.0-alpha.19","2.0.0-alpha.20","2.0.0-alpha.21","2.0.0-alpha.22","2.0.0-alpha.23","2.0.0-alpha.24","2.0.0-alpha.25","2.0.0-alpha.26","2.0.0-alpha.27","2.0.0-alpha.28","2.0.0-alpha.29","2.0.0-alpha.30","2.0.0-alpha.31","2.0.0-alpha.32"]
```

Comment: The newest version is `2.0.0-rc.4`. To my surprise,  [official tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files) always keeps track of the newest version. Good job!

Comment: @Zen how should the command look like today?  npm install angular2@2.0.0-rc.4 or what? I am trying to learn some frontend and get stuck at configuration part of angular on my ubuntu.....

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
npm install angular2 -g
```

That worked for me and installed angularJS2 alpha32. You can append flag --save to store the name of the module in an existing package.json if appropriate.

EDIT: the -g attribute would install angular2 globally, removing -g would install locally which should be preferred!

Later, if possible, I would prefer installing Angular2 another way, that is with Bower:

```
bower install angular2
```

Comment: That worked for me. Did you use the exact command?
Good that the solution of Jesse Good worked but I wonder why you have to state a version number. That is not necessary with the above command: it takes the actual version.

Comment: In my case firstly I installed directly `npm` with `apt-get install npm` (Ubuntu). Later when I tried to install `tsd` from `npm` it didn't work, so I followed this [installation instructions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) (this will install `npm` and `tsd`), and finally I installed angular with `tsd install angular2` and that worked. Maybe there are differences between those `npm` packages. (Just leaving this here in case it helps someone).

Comment: This is a terrible idea. This would install angular2 globally.

Comment: If you intend to use Angular2 globally it is not that terrible. But yes, normally you need Angular for certain projects and not globally.

Comment: I was confused with comments from @prasanthv but the rev shows that Pille had removed the -g flag in a later edit. it would have been better to leave that line with a comment that the -g flag would cause global install and removing it will do a local install.

Comment: @SuryaPratap Agreed thank you! I edited my answer and added the possibilty to install Angular2 with Bower.

Answer (score 1):

What version of NPM are you running? Try updating it if providing the tag didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found deleting my .npmrc file (in my user dir) fixed my issues installing angular2 and reactivex/rxjs.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to look into this. Jesse Good's suggestion worked. But the original command should have worked as well.